# How to enable gpu acceleration on laptop for ros?

Tags: ros, rviz, gpu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I m trying to simulate Intel Realsense camera on Asus Tuf A15 with 1650ti GPU and 16GB ram. Whenever I enable pointcloud2  in rviz fps drops to 2-3fps. I guess rviz is not using my GPU. Is there any way to enable the GPU acceleration? I could not find any support.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402831/how-to-enable-gpu-acceleration-on-laptop-for-ros?/) by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2022-06-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-06-24**:
did you searched it in the web?

https://discourse.ros.org/t/challenges-of-gpu-acceleration-in-ros/19297

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2022-06-27**:
I'm not aware of any ways to force rviz to use a GPU (though they may exist). There is a way to force it to *not* use a gpu, per http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Troubleshooting so you could make sure that `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE` isn't set to true... A few things to check..

- if you are using Gazebo to simulate the sensor, check that you are using the `gazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so` plugin and not the default "cpu" variant (`gazebo_ros_laser.so`)
- if you start rviz by itself, what is the output related to the graphics drivers? Do you see something like this that indicates that your Nvidia driver is being used?

  [/rviz_1637200062035959003.RenderSystem::detectGlVersion]: OpenGL device: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080/PCIe/SSE2
  [/rviz_1637200062035959003.RenderSystem::detectGlVersion]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6).
- if not, maybe run `nvidia-smi` to check that your driver is running

**Comment by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on 2022-07-07**:
Thank you so much. I tried reinstalling the Nvidia drivers and it worked.

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2022-07-07**:
Glad that worked out! Just moving my comment to the answers below so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*Update: in this case, the issue was a faulty NVIDIA driver*

I'm not aware of any ways to force rviz to use a GPU (though they may exist). There is a way to force it to not use a gpu, per http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Troubleshooting so you could make sure that LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE isn't set to true... A few things to check..

if you are using Gazebo to simulate the sensor, check that you are using the gazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so plugin and not the default "cpu" variant (gazebo_ros_laser.so)
if you start rviz by itself, what is the output related to the graphics drivers? Do you see something like this that indicates that your Nvidia driver is being used?

[/rviz_1637200062035959003.RenderSystem::detectGlVersion]: OpenGL device: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080/PCIe/SSE2 [/rviz_1637200062035959003.RenderSystem::detectGlVersion]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6).

if not, maybe run nvidia-smi to check that your driver is running

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2022-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on 2022-07-08**:
Yes... Initially, I was checking it using nvidia-smi. I could only see the gazebo using the GPU. After reinstalling the driver RViz finally started using the GPU. Thank you for the coomment.

**Comment by [ThomasL624](https://answers.ros.org/users/50229/thomasl624/) on 2022-11-21**:
@Saurabh Rahatekar could you elaborate more which driver you have reinstalled? I am also facing the same issue, when enable pointlcoud2 topic, the fps drops to 1-5fps, I have checked the nvidia-smi is running and cuda 11.6 with cudnn8 is installed. The driver version would be 515. My GPU card is a RTX3090.

How do you know which application is using GPU from Nvidia-smi?

**Comment by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on 2022-11-21**:
Open your terminal with dedicated graphics. And then launch the RViz. It will solve ypur problem. Nvidia-smi shows the processes which are using gpu.

**Comment by [ThomasL624](https://answers.ros.org/users/50229/thomasl624/) on 2022-11-21**:
What do you mean by that? normally i start up the terminal with default hot keys… Nvidia-smi command can be used in normal terminal.

**Comment by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on 2022-11-21**:
Right click on the terminal icon and you will see the dedicated graphics option. Then launch the RViz from that terminal, RViz will start using the GPU.

**Comment by [ThomasL624](https://answers.ros.org/users/50229/thomasl624/) on 2022-11-23**:
I only got 3 options (New windows, preference, remove from favorite). I am running on  a Ubuntu 20.04 pc

**Comment by [Saurabh Rahatekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/56348/saurabh-rahatekar/) on 2022-11-23**:
Yes I m running the same ubuntu version. Try reinstalling the gpu drivers or google your issue. I hope you find the solution.

**Comment by [ThomasL624](https://answers.ros.org/users/50229/thomasl624/) on 2022-11-24**:
I will try reinstall the cuda driver on host and see the result